# Is there another solution to this problem?

Tags: geometry

Take a half circle with radius 2r with the center of O. Now take the half points from the radiuses from O forming the border of the half circle and draw two more half circles with radius r. Finally draw a circle touching the original half circle from the inside and the smaller half circles from the outside. What's the radius of this circle?

So let x be the radius in question, the centre of one of the smaller half circles be A, the centre of the circle in question C, then OC is 2r-x, AC is x+r and OA is r. With the Pythagorean theorem, $(r+x)^2=r^2+(2r-x)^2$, $x=2/3r$.

[image]

http://ggbm.at/v6XZM74R

Is there a way to prove this without the Pythagorean theorem? Similar triangles? Alternatively, how would you do a compass-and-straightedge construction?

Comment: A diagram would be very helpful.  I recommend geogebra.  You have the rep to post a graphic.

Comment: @RossMillikan I tried :)

Comment: For a compass-and-straightedge construction just draw OC line, the perpendicular on OA. Because $OC = {\frac 4 3}r=r + {\frac 1 3}r$ it's easy to construct the point C.

Comment: @EugenCovaci of course but that requires solving the problem w/ the Pythagorean theorem first to know it's 4/3r . I was interested in a direct construction method that doesn't require this knowledge much rather yields this knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

By [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point), $R(R + 2x) = (2x – R)^2$. It gives $R = \dfrac {2x}{3}$.

Comment: This is perhaps the most elegant. (Except for the notation, I used x for the unknown variable as customary which you used R for. Doesn't matter.)

Comment: @chx Will take more care next time..

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the point on $AC$ where the circles touch. Draw from $T$ the common tangent to intersect $OC$ at $P$. Let $OP=PT=a$, so that $PC=2r-x-a$. From the similarity of $AOC$ and $PTC$ you get two equations and can solve for $x$ and $a$:
$$
(2r-a-x):(x+r)=a:r=x:(2r-x).
$$

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let us consider the case $r = \frac12$ first.

Choose a coordinate system so that $OA$ is the $x$-axis and $OC$ is the $y$-axis.
The bigger half circle now has radius $1$. Perform a [circle inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion) with respect to it, we find:

- The bigger half circle get mapped to itself.
- Since the inversion sends $O$ to infinity and the two smaller half circles (red and orange) passes through $O$, they get mapped to two rays (the two dashed lines in red and orange ) parallel to $y$-axis at $x = \pm 1$.
- Notice circle inversion preserve tangency among curves.

  Since the small circle (green circle with solid boundary) is tangent to the three half circles, 
  it get mapped to a circle (green circle with dashed boundary) tangent to the bigger half circle and
  the two rays.

  There are only one way to place such a circle. It will have radius $1$ and intersects $y$-axis at $D = (0,1)$ and $E = (0,3)$.
- Invert it back, the original small circle intersect $y$-axis at $D = (0,1)$ and $E' = (0,\frac13)$.
  This means it will have center $C' = (0,\frac23)$ and radius $\frac12(1-\frac13) = \frac13 = \frac23 r$.

By scaling, the expression $\frac23 r$ works for other values of $r$.

$\hspace1in$ [image: A circle in half circle]

Comment: > The small circle becomes a circle sandwiched these two rays.  
  It intersects $y$-axis at $(0,1)$ and $(0,3)$. - Why?

Comment: This is because circle inversion maps circles to circles (lines in the special case the circle pass through the inversion center) and preserve tangency. If the small circle is touching the three half circles, then under circle inversion, it will get mapped to a circle touching the half circle and the two rays. There is only one way to place the circle.

Comment: This is incredibly tricky.

Comment: @chx this may sounds tricky but once you are familiar with circle inversion, you can solve this problem inside the brain.